# Send JWT token in a custom header instead of "Authorization" header in Swagger UI

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, swagger, swagger-ui

I have this swagger configuration in .net 7 c# web api to prepare swagger UI for the OAuth2 authorization and It's working perfectly as I wanted but I need to have a little modification.
After I enter the correct data and swagger UI retrieve the token successfully the token is injected in the normal http "Authorization" header which is perfect.
I just want to send the token in another header for example "jwt-token" header instead of using the normal "Authorization" header.

```
options.AddSecurityDefinition(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    OpenIdConnectUrl = new Uri(authConfig.Authority ?? throw new NullReferenceException("Failed to get signing authority from config")),
    Description = $"KeyCloak JWT-I token.",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
    Name = "Authorization",
    Scheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
    {
        Password = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
        {
            TokenUrl = new Uri(authConfig.AuthTokenProxy
                ?? authConfig.AuthTokenEndpoint
                ?? throw new NullReferenceException("Failed to get auth token endpoint or proxy from config")),
            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "openid", "The default OpenId scope" }
        }
        }
    }
});

options.AddSecurityRequirement(
    new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = ApiKeyDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                },
            },
            new List<string>()
        }
    });
```

[image]

I have tried to play around with swagger ui configuration but I had no clue.
What expected is to inject js file to alter the default behaviour of swagger so I can send the token in another header than the "Authorization" header.